# apply the filter expression to ultragrid

Tags: infragistics

i have a main ultragrid and a secondary ultragrid. there are filters applied to the main ultragrid. 
according to the filter applied,i get the result on main grid.
I want to fetch the filter from the main grid and apply the same filter to the
secondary ultragrid.
the filters on main grid have been achieved through the ultragrid property.
So, i dnt have to create the filter. I will get the filter expression already made.
i just have to attach dat filter to secondary ultragrid.
but it seems i dnt hav any option to apply the filter to secondary ultragrid

Comment: The grids have the same schema?

Comment: No @Steve the schema of the grids aren't same. the main ultragrid has some data and secondary grid has related data about a row been selected on main ultragrid

Comment: So, let me check if I have understood your question. On the first grid you have a filter applied with the grid user interface. You want the same filter applied to the second grid? automatically? But this requires the second grid to have at least a subset of the same columns of the first grid otherwise you can't apply the same filter for every possible columns of the first grid

Comment: there is just one column common in both the grid which is unique

Comment: Why do you need to apply a filter to the second grid if it is only displaying details based on the selection of the first grid?  You will only be able to select rows that are not filtered out in the first grid to determine what is displayed in the second grid.